# Fetching Users information from Azure AD B2C and displaying on .NET web application

Tags: c#, html, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup Azure AD B2C for my project in .NET MVC. Its working perfectly. Now i want to fetch user information (who ever has signed up) from Azure side and display in my .NET MVC application.
Any good links I can refer or any suggestions will be very helpful to start with.

I have started with some setups like granting permission for user read in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD B2C users tokens cannot be used against MS Graph API to fetch data, so you have 2 options.

1. In your .Net App use client credentials to get an App token to MS Graph API and fetch the users data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service
2. Rather than fetching the data from MS Graph API, insert the data to begin with into the AAD B2C token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#include-a-claim-in-the-token

Or for User Flows, add the claim to the Application Claims section.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It helps me to some extent.